# T-Sql returning XML column data as a node in a FOR XML query

Tags: xml, t-sql, for-xml-path

I have a view in SQL Server 2005 that contains a column of xml data. The column comes from a `for xml path()` query, ie

```
SELECT     e.id, eventTypeCode, e.startDate, e.endDate,
(select v.name 
 from venue v inner 
 join eventVenue ev on ev.venueCode=v.code 
 where ev.eventId=e.id for xml path('venue')) as venues    
FROM dbo.event e 
inner join eventType t on e.eventTypeCode=t.code
```

I now want to refer to this view in a stored procedure that returns data as xml, ie

```
create procedure getWebsiteMainCalendarEvents
@startDate datetime,
@endDate datetime
as
select * from vwWebsiteMainCalendar 
 where startDate between @startDate and @endDate 
order by startDate for xml path() element
```

I'd like the venues from the view to appear as subnodes when I run the procedure, but `<` and `>` are encoded as html entities. Is there a way to get the procedure to treat xml data as an xml node in the output?

Comment: I've sorted it. The view needed to have 'type' attached to the for xml path(), ie

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it. The view should have had 'type' attached to the for xml path(), ie

```
-- VENUES
(select v.name from venue v inner join eventVenue ev on ev.venueCode=v.code where ev.eventId=e.id for xml path('venue'))
```

should be

```
-- VENUES
```

(select v.name from venue v inner join eventVenue ev on ev.venueCode=v.code where ev.eventId=e.id for xml path('venue'), **type**)